# I can't see warnings/ runtime errors in VSCODE C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, runtime-error, compiler-warnings

I used to work in visual studio a lot but for competitive programming I switched to VS-CODE because it is faster and I have special extensions. But I have some problems setting up my environment... I can't see any warning or any runtime error... I searched everywhere, I tried everything and it does not work.. any ideas?
Here is a snippet:
[image]

Comment: What's in your output window?

Comment: All those `typedef`s look like you're trying to encrypt your code. Don't do that because it makes debugging much harder.

Comment: If the output tab doesn't contain what you're looking for, you'll probably have to add the JSON scripts you edited when configuring VSCode to the question. The information needed to solve most VSCode problems is inside the configuration.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: Yep... I want to see the warnings in the problems tab... and if any show runtime error... as you can see.. wan i run my code in terminal it doesnt show nothing

Comment: If the program has a nasty enough bug to kill it before any output can be flushed to the console only a debugger (or careful analysis of the code. Debugger's usually faster) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure you have the [Microsoft CPP Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) installed, then follow these steps:

You should make sure that you have a problemMatcher in your project tasks.json file

```
"problemMatcher": "$gcc"
```

Then you should add this to your settings.json file

```
 "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
```

And lastly, go to command palette:  Ctrl + Shift + P

and search

[image: Run code analysis]

Then, open your terminal again (in VSCODE)

and find the Problems tab, and now it should show you what is wrong

[image: Problem tab]